# Backup Google Authenticator transferring QR code

Tags: multi-factor, google, one-time-password, backup, authenticator

I understand that saving a screenshot of the QR code during the OTP setup process is enough to back up a single account, however, is this the same for the QR code generated during the Google Authenticator transferring process? Because, if so, could this QR code be able to serve as a backup of Google Authenticator accounts?

Comment: Hi and welcome on StackExchange. This is a great question.

Comment: Thank you, @Marcel, I hope to learn and contribute with other people here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it contains all the keys so it can serve as a backup.

Making such a backup causes a google authenticator to display a warning, so keep your phone away from others until that warning expires, else you'll not be able to tell if they have also cloned your keys.

Comment: I can confirm this and have successfully used this for quite a bunch of keys. The QR code grows large, but it works. Alternatively you could also just select some keys at a time and repeat multiple times.